# Check most frequently accessed file in github

Tags: git, github

I have a repository in github. this has a number of directories and files. Is there a command to check the most frequently accessed file?

Comment: maybe this could help : https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this kind of info using GitHub REST API.

```
curl -u $your_username https://api.github.com/repos/$username/$reponame/traffic/popular/paths
```

This command prints JSON array with top 10 popular contents over the last 14 days.

You must have push access to the repository. GitHub will ask your password.

Comment: Thanks , but I am getting redirected to 404 (page not found)

Comment: very interesting, but make sure that your specified repository really exists, and there is no a typo

Comment: the repo does existing , but is it required for insight plugin to be installed & for the user to have access? also should repo name be a combination of space name / repo name?

Comment: of course, the user should have access, but no plugin is needed; the combination of username/reponame in the URL identifies the repository

Comment: look, it works for me, and those repositories exist - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOID0.png

Answer (score 1):

No.  There's no way to tell what files people are looking at.  If they check out a repository, they can be looking at your files all day long but that doesn't report back to GitHub.

Comment: I have Spring cloud config server which I believe checks out a specific file (i may be wrong). If that is the case , is there a way to check?